# How to get (Citrix/Xen) 'xe' tool on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, xen

I have an Xen 7.6 cluster and I need to update the patches. Where do I get the 'xe' application from (for CentOS 7)? I see references to the 'guest-tools' that get installed to manage new VMs but this app isn't supplied.

It appears that this app is installed with the Xencenter executable on windows.

Answer (score 1):

You want `xe-guest-utilities` which comes from `EPEL` but also `xe-guest-utilities-xenstore`.

You can install the first with `yum` but to get the second one which contains the app, you will need the file `guest-tools.iso`.

Mount the iso:

```
mnt -o loop /path/to/guest-tools.iso /mnt/iso
```

There will then be an `install.sh` file located inside at `/mnt/iso/Linux/install.sh`. You can install it with

```
bash /mnt/iso/Linux/install.sh
```

That will install the following assuming that you didn't install the first one with `yum`:

```
xe-guest-utilities
xe-guest-utilities-xenstore
```

That will give you the app that you need.

There is a step-by-step on this here:

https://xen-orchestra.com/blog/install-xenserver-tools-in-your-vm/

It's written for Centos 6 but it still works for Centos 7.

Comment: That package doesn't provide the 'xe' app.

Comment: @ethrbunny See my edit.